# Closure under polynomial reduction

Tags: complexity-theory

Having some trouble generalizing when a complexity class $D$ is closed under polynomial reduction.

For instance, take the following examples:

1. $\bigcup_{c \ge 1} \mathsf{DTime}(2^{cn^5})$
2. $\bigcup_{c \ge 1} \mathsf{DTime}(5^{cn})$
3. $\bigcup_{c \ge 1} \mathsf{DTime}(n^{c\log^5n})$

$P$ is contained in all of these classes, so if we are given a problem $A$  which belongs to one of those classes, and a reduction from another problem $B$ to $A$, the polynomial reduction won't affect the overall decision run-time. Can it be generalized to any class larger then $P$?

Comment: Try generalizing the proof.

Comment: But is this assumption is correct? I mean, If P is contained in a class, this class is closed to polynomial reduction?

Comment: No. For example, take $\mathsf{P}$ together with $\mathsf{E}$.